# Spring Boot - Database based request mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 2 I want to create a database based request mapping. I mean, instead of using hundreds of `@RequestMapping` annotations on the controllers I would like to store the mapping in a database table.
Each of the controllers implements an interface that has an execute method so I simply search for the relevant controller in the DB and call the execute method on it.

At the moment I have a `CustomController` with a `@RequestMapping("*")` and this controller finds the real controller and calls the execute method. It works but it is not a good solution. For example at interceptor level the handler object is the `CustomController` and not the real controller.

Probably I should use the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` like this:

```
@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();

    Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
    urlMap.put("/dashboard", __???__);
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

    return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
}
```

But in this case I don't know how to fill the bean value in the `urlMap`. For example in case of "/dashboard" how to put the `DashboardController.execute()`.

Maybe any better solution?

**UPDATE 1**

I have created a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleUrlHandlerMappingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();

        String path = "/dashboard";
        String controllerName = "dashboardController";

        Object myController = context.getBean(controllerName);

        urlMap.put(path, myController);
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
    }

}
```

And a `CustomHandlerAdapter` as:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomHandlerAdapter implements HandlerAdapter {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Object handler) {
        logger.debug("Test handler: " + handler);
        if (handler instanceof PageController) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Custom handle");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        String viewName = ((PageController)handler).execute2(request, response);
        mv.setViewName(viewName);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

But according to logs it seems that `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` doesn't work correctly:

```
- DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/dashboard]
- Looking up handler method for path /dashboard
- Did not find handler method for [/dashboard]
- Matching patterns for request [/dashboard] are [/**]
- URI Template variables for request [/dashboard] are {}
- Mapping [/dashboard] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4bc6044e]]] and 1 interceptor
- Test handler: ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4bc6044e]]
- Last-Modified value for [/dashboard] is: -1
```

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to `@M. Deinum` I have updated my code and have a working solution.
Please note that `@EnableWebMvc` was introduced and that can cause other side effects later.

The SimpleUrlHandlerMappingConfig:

```
@Configuration()
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleUrlHandlerMappingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();

        String path = "/dashboard";
        String controllerName = "dashboardController";

        Object myController = context.getBean(controllerName);

        urlMap.put(path, myController);
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
    }

}
```

The CustomHandlerAdapter:

```
@Component
public class CustomHandlerAdapter implements HandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Object handler) {
        if (handler instanceof PageController) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        String viewName = ((PageController)handler).execute2(request, response);
        mv.setViewName(viewName);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And the WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/style/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:" + "/static/style/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:" + "/static/js/");

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a custom `HandlerAdapter` that knows how to handle your custom interface (i.e. call the `execute` method). For the mappings create a custom `HandlerMapping` or simply fill the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` with the data from the database. Nonetheless you would need a custom `HandlerAdapter` for your class.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, I have tried your proposal, but seems I still missing something as you can see in my updated post.

Comment: Your `CustomHandlerAdapter` shouldn't be an `@Configuration` but rather an `@Component` or just a regular `@Bean` in your configuration. You also want to set an `order` on the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` you might want to use the highest order, `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`. Else it will be executed after the other handler mappings.

Comment: The base concept works if I add `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to my `WebConfig` class, however in this case serving static content stopped working.

Comment: I have added a `resourceHandlers` for my `WebConfig` and now it works fine with `@EnableWebMvc`, however I don't know what other side effects the `@EnableWebMvc` will cause.

Comment: Adding `@EnableWebMvc` disables Spirng Boot auto configuration. Setting an `order` should fix the issue you had without disabling parts of Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Maybe I'm doing it wrong but setting the order - using the `Order` annotation on the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` as you can see in Update 2 - has no effect. I got the same error as in Update 1 case.

Comment: Using the annotation won’t help. As stated set the order property.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get rid of the simple actions (get/post/put/delete) -- and those only call the save/find/delete methods from the repository.
If that is the case I suggest using [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

Answer (score 0):

I post the final solution (thanks  to M. Deinum) here maybe helping somebody else.

So I only created a `HandlerMapping` using the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`:

```
@Configuration()
public class SimpleUrlHandlerMappingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        Map<String, Object> urlMap = new HashMap<>();

        String path = "/dashboard";
        String controllerName = "dashboardController";

        Object myController = context.getBean(controllerName);

        urlMap.put(path, myController);
        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(urlMap);

        simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
    }

}
```

And a custom `HandlerAdapter`:

```
@Component
public class CustomHandlerAdapter implements HandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Object handler) {
        if (handler instanceof PageController) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        String viewName = ((PageController)handler).execute2(request, response);
        mv.setViewName(viewName);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Please note that this example demonstrates only the concept without proper error handling and real DB access.